# How to define a type with list of java.util.objects in graphql-java

Tags: graphql-java

I have a schema where the json can have a list of Int and Strings as values. I am wondering how to define a type of resolver for my scenario.

```
type Total {
  key: String
  values: [Object]
}

type Query {
  filter (key : String!) : Total
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concept of *general object* (as *Object* in Java) in GraphQL. In fact, the defined type are the following (as described [here](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#scalar-types)):

1. Int: A signed 32‐bit integer;
2. Float: A signed double-precision floating-point value;
3. String: A UTF‐8 character sequence;
4. Boolean: true or false;
5. ID: The ID scalar type represents a unique identifier, often used to refetch an object or as the key for a cache. The ID type is serialized in the same way as a String; however, defining it as an ID signifies that it is not intended to be human‐readable.

You could define a new scalar but it means that you will have to define yourself how it would be serialized/deserialized and validated. It add way more complexity for not much value. Moreover, I feel that the **strong** typing of Graphql is completely lost with this specific type.

I think your best bet is to use the [**Interfaces**](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#interfaces). With an interface and using *wrapper types*, you are then able to model this *general object* that you are talking about, and would help you write a schema as follow:

```
interface MyInterface {
    // must have a field at least (cannot be empty)
    id: ID!
}

type MyInt implements MyInteface {
    // Inherited by MyInterface
    id: ID!

    myIntValue: Int
}

type MyString implements MyInteface {
    // Inherited by MyInterface
    id: ID!

    myStringValue: String
}

type Total {
    key : String
    values: [MyInterface]
}

type Query {
    filter(key: String!) : Total
}
```

**Careful**: please note that the interface isn't allowed to be empty (no fields). For that purpose, I added an ID field that is by implementation *randomly* generated.

With such a schema, we are able to perform a query like the following:

```
filter("someFilter") {
    key
    values {
        ... on MyString {
            myStringValue
        }
        ... on MyInt {
            myIntValue
        }
    }
}
```

For that to work you would need to define a TypeResolver, as follow:

```java
private class MyInterfaceTypeResolver implements TypeResolver {
    @Override
    public GraphQLObjectType getType(TypeResolutionEnvironment env) {
        Object obj = env.getObject();

        if (obj instanceOf MyInt) {
            env.getSchema().getObjectType("MyInt");
        } else if (obj instanceOf MyString) {
            env.getSchema().getObjectType("MyString");
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

with the following Java types definition:

```java
abstract class MyInterface {
    private String id;

    public MyInterface() {
        // Generated just to avoid empty graphql interface
        id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

class MyInt extends MyInterface {
    private Integer myIntValue;

    public MyInt(Integer myInt) {
        super();
        this.myIntValue= myInt;
    }

    public Integer getMyIntValue() {
        return myInt;
    }
}

class MyString extends MyInterface {
    private String myStringValue;

    public MyString (String myString) {
        super();
        this.myStringValue= myString;
    }

    public String getMyStringValue() {
        return myStringValue;
    }
}
```

Assuming that you want to represent the following Json `{"key": "myKey", "values":[12,"String1", 1, "String2"]}`, given our previous model and query, it would be represented like this:

```
{
   "data": {
       "filter": {
           "key": "myKey",
           "values" : [
               {
                   "myIntValue": 12
               },
               {
                   "myStringValue": "String1"
               },
               {
                   "myIntValue": 1
               },
               {
                   "myStringValue": "String2"
               }
           ]
       }
   }
}
```

Lastly, you could just have multiple attributs, one for each type, such as follow:

```
type Total {
    key : String
    valuesInt: [Int]
    valuesString: [String]
}

type Query {
    filter(key: String!) : Total
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the resolver as well. I am not sure how using interface, it will be able to render something like this

{
   key : "Tot",
   values : ["Value1", 234,143, "Value2" ]
}

Comment: Updated with an example

Comment: @D.Lawrence While this approach works for Type, I would add that Input do not support interfaces.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!!